# Why does Datastax ODBC not accept "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)"?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I am trying to install [DataStax ODBC driver for Hive on Windows](http://datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaHivODBC.html). I have a "Windows 7 Ultimate N (64bit)" installation and every time I try to start the installer for the ODBC Driver I get an error saying I need to install Visual C++ 2010 runtime:

[image: error saying I need to install Visual C++ 2010 runtime].

I have done that. In fact, I even upgraded to [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328) to see if that worked. Still, I am getting the same error. Here's a screenshot of the Visual C++ "programs" I have installed:

[image: screenshot of the Visual C++ "programs" I have installed].

Question: Is there anything that I can do to debug this further? Am I missing something? I am somewhat unfamiliar with the Windows environment.

Comment: To the people who are downvoting this, let me know why you are downvoting, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're showing that you have installed the 2010 32 bit runtime (x86), while it asks for the the 64 bit runtime (x64).

From what I can gather, you need to install [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

(imo. Someone should file a bug with Datastax and ask them to include that redistributable package to create less hassle for the users).

Comment: Good catch. Installed the right package and now the ODBC package installs.